# How to fix incorrect rounding of float to integer in Frog Jump assignment?

Tags: java

Why performance tests fails on [my solution](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingGRT2G4-RF7/):

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
        return (int) Math.ceil((Y-X)/(float)D);
    }
}
```

How to improve?

**Tests:**

```
public class SolutionTest {
    private Solution solution;

    @Test
    public void defaultTest(){
        assertEquals(3, solution.solution(10,85,30));
    }
    @Test
    public void many_jump1Test(){
        assertEquals(499999998, solution.solution(-499999996,500000000,2));
    }
    @Before
    public void init(){
        solution = new Solution();
    }
}
```

Comment: "This question does not appear to be about programming "  - Really?

Comment: Don't see no "performance tests".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is running into rounding errors, because of the lack of precision in a `float`. Your test results state that:

> For the input (3, 999111321, 7) the solution returned a wrong answer (got 142730192 expected 142730189).

Given that input, let's have a look at the result of `(X - Y) / D` if we use a `float`, and if we use a `double`:

```
float f = (999111321 - 3) / 7.0f;  // 1.42730192E8
double d = (999111321 - 3) / 7.0;  // 1.427301882857143E8
                                              ^^
```

Note the rounding error on the last two digits before the decimal point. In order to avoid this and to get the right answer, you just need to cast `D` to a `double` instead of to a `float` in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Integer operations are by far faster, and an integer division, might be used:

```
(Y - X + D - 1) / D
```

Normally `/ D` would give the floor value. In order to receive the ceil value add `D - 1`.

This saves:

- A `double` division
- Taking `Math.ceil()`
- Converting to `int`